# Broken (tag) links on SE.com search results

Tags: bug

I was looking where I could possibly ask a question about Mailman, so I searched on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=mailman).

I expected the tag links in the result list, i.e. `mailman`, `mailman-gem`, etc, to open the tag search in the respective SE sites, or on SO, but they result in a `Page Not Found` on SE.com:

> https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mailman